# How to use a specific commit of dependency packages in Flutter application?

Tags: git, flutter

I forked a package from GitHub and had several commits on it.  I want to use a specific commit in a project. How to use a specific commit in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Package dependencies > Dependency sources > Git packages](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages) in the Dart docs:

> ```
> dependencies:
>   kittens:
>     git:
>       url: git@github.com:munificent/kittens.git
>       ref: some-branch
> ```
>
> The ref can be anything that Git allows to [identify a commit](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#naming-commits).

So you can write your commit hash as the value for `ref:` to use that specific commit.

Answer (score 0):

another way is like this:

```
  flutter_cool_card_swiper:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/flutter_cool_card_swiper
```